# what are the parameters taking attention of Windows compatibility?

Tags: windows, compatibility

I wonder what are the parameters or API which may take Windows compatibility attention during running the exe or installer? Whenever I run the exe, it calls for Windows compatibility manager. Is it because of wrong use of any WinAPI? Or are there other parameters which can cause Windows attention for checking compatibility of any exe?

Comment: I suppose, that'a all about the manifest embedded in the .exe or .dll (and its contents of course)

Comment: Hey @ quetzalcoatl i have found this link while googling

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756937.aspx

as per this Programs commonly use the GetVersion function or the GetVersionEx APIs to get information on the Windows OS version they are running on. Under Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008, these APIs will return 6 as the major version. If the program is hard-coded to look for the XP version, which is major version 5, it will fail under Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008.

I got confused after reading this link. any suggestion.

Comment: Years ago, there was a time when XP was a new operating system that introduced some new mechanisms and new APIs. At this time, "really old" windows had a major version number of 4-or-less and "new" ones (that is, XP-class) had a major version number of 5. Developers used to manually inspect the `GetVersion` to check whether the application is running on "old" or "new" system, just to NOT try to use the new APIs on an "old" system. Some developers tend to overlook that version numbers evolve. They wrote their checks as `if version == 5` instead of `if version >= 5`.

Comment: So, the note at MSDN reminds, that every version check written as `if version == 5` **will fail** on an operating system yet newer than XP. For example, Vista has a major of 6. So, a check `if version == 5` will fail on Vista, ignoring that 6 is newer than 5, and thus ignoring the fact that the set of those new APIs introduced in WinXP is present at Vista. If you run such program on Vista, this program will think that it is being run i.e. on Win98

Comment: Thanks quetzalcoatl, there is a check in my program too for windows version. I am getting version using GetVersionEx() through OSVERSIONINFO structure and check for version osversioninfo.dwMajorVersion >= 6 for windows 7. Can this be the issue, which will be taking windows attention for check this exe compatibility issue for windows ?

Comment: GetVersion/Ex returns a number. When you call that function, Windows just returns you some number. Windows does not check WHAT are you doing with that number. You may multiply it by 111 and subtract 555 and check if the result is equal to zero. Whatever. The note on MSDN only reminds you to be careful when you are inspecting that number.

Answer (score 0):

The 'compatibility options' that windows are displaying when you run the application are NOT about `GetVersionEx`. **I think** that this dialog pops up when the Manifest is missing and/or when it indicates a different Windows system than your computer has installed.

If users of your application see that compatibility popup, please ensure that your manifest is correct. This articles may be a good start:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb757005.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756937.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371711.aspx